# How can I measure duration from search submit click to full load of results page?

Tags: performance, analytics

I want to measure how much time it takes from the moment a "Submit" button is clicked on a search form until the results page that a user is then taken to is fully loaded.

Effectively, I'm trying to measure how long it takes to fully return search results including whatever processes are running on the form page and the subsequent results page.

Has anybody done this with Google Analytics or a different tool or method?

Answer (score 0):

In your browser, press F12, in network tab,  you can see time taken by request, add time taken to render data with that